# Build a N depth structure for a series of validation results in C#

Tags: c#, data-structures, recursive-datastructures

**Background**

I have a following set of `ValidationResult` data. It's `List<ValidationResult>`.

**FYI**

It contains two types actually. I made a custom validation result, implementing `ValidationResult` to collect all errors in a model. So this set of data has actually two types of data. One is `ValidationResult` and another is `CustomValidationResult`.

```
[0] { "Name Field shouldn't be null" }
[1] { "Money Field should be in range 0 and 100" }
[2] { "Validation failed at CompanyList" } // This is CustomValidationResult
  ㄴ [0] { "CompanyName Field shouldn't be null" } // ValidationResult inside of CustomValidationResult.
  ㄴ [1] { "Validation failed at DepartmentList" } // Belows are same as above
       ㄴ [0] { "DepartmentName Field shouldn't be null" }
       ㄴ [1] { "Validation failed at EmployeeList" }
            ㄴ [0] { "EmployeeName Field shouldn't be null" }
            ㄴ [1] { "EmployeeEmail Field's format should be Email" }
```

This is the result of the `Validator.TryValidateObject(model, context, true)` method, the built-in, static function in `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Validator`.

Anyway I want to make the set of result look prettier in order to easily access the individual errors. I'm thinking of "Key" "Value" structure, so that I can find out easily which properties was failed in validation process.

```
// I want the result to look something like this below.

[0] { "Name", "Name Field Shouldn't be null" }
[1] { "Money", "Money Field should be in range 0 and 100" }
[2] { "CompanyList", "Validation failed at CompanyList" }
  ㄴ [0] { "CompanyName", "CompanyName Field shouldn't be null" }
  ㄴ [1] { "DepartmentList", "Validation failed at DepartmentList" }
       ㄴ [0] { "DepartmentName", "DepartmentName Field shouldn't be null" }
       ㄴ [1] { "EmployeeList", "Validation failed at EmployeeList" }
            ㄴ [0] { "EmployeeName", "EmployeeName Field shouldn't be null" }
            ㄴ [1] { "EmployeeEmail", "EmployeeEmail Field's format should be Email" }
```

**PROBLEM**

But "PropertyName", "ErrorMessage" key value model can't form a N-depth structure like this. I'm at a loss what to do.

**QUESTION**

- How should I model a data structure for this?
- What would be the best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build a `ValidationResultNode` that looks like this:

```
class ValidationResultNode
{
    public string PropertyName {get; private set;}
    public string ErrorMessage {get; private set;}
    public List<ValidationResultNode> Children {get; private set;}
    public ValidationResult(string propName, string errMsg)
    {
        PropertyName = propName;
        ErrorMessage = errMsg;
        Children = new List<ValidationResultNode>();
    }

    // method to add a child error
    public ValidationResultNode AddChildError(string propName, string errMsg)
    {
        var result = new ValidationResultNode(propName, errMsg);
        Children.Add(result);
        return result;
    }
```

It's basically a hierarchical tree implemented as nested lists.

If you're using Windows Forms, look into the [TreeView class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview(v=vs.110).aspx) if you want to display this. For WPF, look into the [WPF TreeView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.treeview(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I ended up making an object like this. I was hoping that there is some fancy ways to achieve the goal in .NET. Somewhat I really wanted to avoid make a nested object in it. But come to think of it, it wasn't just impossible at the first place.